# Compiling new driver for Wi-Fi adapter (TP-WN823N) fails

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am new to Ubuntu and when I was trying to install a new driver for my Wi-Fi adapter (TP-WN823N) because my internet on Ubuntu is way slower than it was using Windows (my download rate is anywhere between a third and a half of what it used to be).

I followed the steps of the instructions it came with, which are from 2018 and therefore use another OS-version (16.04, I have 18.04) kernel (4.13.0-36-generic vs. 5.3.0-46-generic) and gcc (5.4.0 vs. 7.5.0)  than I have currently installed. I think this is why it fails to execute `make`.

Using `make` creates this text:

```
je@924NDA:~/Dokumente$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/build M=/home/je/Dokumente  modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic“ wird betreten
  CC [M]  /home/je/Dokumente/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/je/Dokumente/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                 from /home/je/Dokumente/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/je/Dokumente/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/je/Dokumente/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/je/Dokumente/include/osdep_service_linux.h:299:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/je/Dokumente/include/osdep_service_linux.h:300:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /home/je/Dokumente/include/drv_types.h:30:0,
                 from /home/je/Dokumente/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/je/Dokumente/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/je/Dokumente/include/wifi.h:1031:0: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
 
In file included from /home/je/Dokumente/include/osdep_service_linux.h:83:0,
                 from /home/je/Dokumente/include/osdep_service.h:47,
                 from /home/je/Dokumente/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/je/Dokumente/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1441:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:288: recipe for target '/home/je/Dokumente/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/je/Dokumente/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/home/je/Dokumente' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/je/Dokumente] Error 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic“ wird verlassen
Makefile:1828: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
je@924NDA:~/Dokumente$ make clean 
#make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/build M=/home/je/Dokumente clean
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
```

`lsusb` output:

```
je@924NDA:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1532:0227 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue like trying to use the versions of the kernel and gcc used in the instructions or changing the code accordingly?

[image: make]

Comment: If the driver you are trying to compile won't build in kernel version 5.3.xx, then it is not a newer driver, but an older driver! It is unlikely to be helpful at all. What driver is installed now? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 done! but I don't know which one could be for the adapter

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless device which has the usb.id of 2357:0109 and mysteriously, no description at all, is covered by the driver 8192eu. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Your wireless should now be working.